# Way to convert 12-bit jpg on linux

Tags: opencv, jpeg

We use OpenCV on linux to read and process regular 8-bit JPGs.

We are now receiving 12-bit JPGs from a specific piece of hardware. OpenCV cannot read these, nor can anything else I've tried. Is there a utility or library for linux that would enable us to process these? Perhaps converting to an 8-bit format?

The latest libjpeg supports 12-bit JPG as a compile-time option. Meaning it would not be easy to write software that supports regular 8-bit and 12-bit jpg at the same time. But I'm wondering if someone has solved this already.

Comment: Maybe imagick: convert orig.jpg -depth 8 output.jpg

Comment: Are you setting `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH` when loading image?

Comment: convert says "convert.im6: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12 `cam0_000000_0.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/316." this is with the Q16 (16-bit) version of image magick.

Comment: I've tried "cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH" and "cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH" from python didn't help. No error but imread returns none.

Comment: I did get something to work. I compiled libjpeg in 12-bit mode, and used its built-in bare-bones djpeg utility plus ImageMagick like this "djpeg input.jpg | convert - out.jpg". So that is a solution. But I'm still interested in a tool or library that does this natively without a special build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of improvements to your proposed technique.

Firstly, you can simplify your process and remove the need to install and be reliant on **ImageMagick** by making `djpeg` emit a `PPM` file, because **OpenCV** can read them anyway without any libraries. So your command would become:

```
djpeg > result.ppm < some12bitBadBoy.jpg
```

Secondly, if you do that, you actually get a 12/16-bit `PPM` file, so you retain more colour resolution into the process!

```
identify -verbose result.ppm

Image: a.ppm
  Format: PPM (Portable pixmap format (color))
  Mime type: image/x-portable-pixmap
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 227x149+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 12-bit                   <---
  Channel depth:
    Red: 12-bit                   <---
    Green: 12-bit                 <---
    Blue: 12-bit                  <---
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 33823
    Red:
      min: 514  (0.125519)
      max: 4095 (1)
      mean: 2350.62 (0.574022)
      standard deviation: 1102.04 (0.269119)
      kurtosis: -1.39076
      skewness: 0.13609
      entropy: 0.971255
    Green:
      min: 305  (0.0744811)
      max: 4095 (1)
      mean: 1453.69 (0.354991)
      standard deviation: 852.147 (0.208095)
      kurtosis: 2.42348
      skewness: 1.77043
      entropy: 0.918006
    Blue:
      min: 213  (0.0520147)
      max: 4095 (1)
      mean: 1309.16 (0.319698)
      standard deviation: 890.453 (0.217449)
      kurtosis: 2.74961
      skewness: 1.92239
...
...
```

For anyone else trying to find an elusive 12-bit JPEG, I *eventually* found one [here](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/tree/master/testimages).

---

A further suggestion, to simplify your workflow, might be to use `inotify` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)) to monitor filesystem events on your image storage area. So you could effectively be notified whenever new JPEGs arrive for analysis, then you could automagically check if 12-bit and generate a corresponding `PPM` file using the procedure above and move the 12-bit JPEG off to some other holding area on disk in case you need to refer back to it.

In case you use Macs, the equivalent is `fswatch` which can be installed with **homebrew**.

Comment: Still requires compiling a 12-bit libjpeg, which I wanted to avoid, but insight here about PPM is valid and useful. Accepted.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't come up with anything more direct - I'll keep it in mind as I wander around the Net and ping you if I come up with anything better. Good luck with your project!